# convert group_by, filter, min() from dplyr to data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I keep failing at converting code from dplyr to data.table because of the min() function

```
df.2 <- df.1 %>% group_by(var1) %>% filter(min(var2, na.rm = TRUE) == var2)
```

Any thoughts and help are greatly appreciated.

Comment: `df.2 <- df.1[ , .SD[min(var2, na.rm = TRUE) == var2], by = var1]`

Comment: An important thing to remember with data.table is that if you filter rows in the first argument of `[` it happens before any grouping. So if you need group logic for the filter, you need to use `.SD` or similar.